# how to pack tkiner object in other class?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
class SettingsFrame(tk.Frame):
    """docstring for SettingsFrame"""
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self = tk.Frame(self.master)

        self.url_label = tk.Label(self, text="Product URL")
        self.url_label.pack(side="left")
        self.url_entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.url_entry.pack(side="left")


class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.settings_frame = SettingsFrame(self)
        self.settings_frame.pack(side="top")

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(master=root)
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm tryining to structure my code as suggested in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17470842/12355344, but I'm not sure how to correctly pack() this `SettingsFrame` with label and entry into `Application` class.

```
AttributeError: 'SettingsFrame' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

Comment: Remove `self.master = master` it's done by default in `Frame.__init__(...`. You should never assign to `self =`, change to `super().__init__(master)`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way:

```
    import tkinter as tk


    class SettingsFrame(tk.Frame):
        """docstring for SettingsFrame"""
        def __init__(self, master=None):
            super().__init__(master)

            self.url_label = tk.Label(self, text="Product URL")
            self.url_label.pack(side="left")
            self.url_entry = tk.Entry(self)
            self.url_entry.pack(side="left")


    class Application(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, master=None):
            super().__init__(master)
            self.settings_frame = SettingsFrame()
            self.settings_frame.pack(side="top")

    def main():
        root = tk.Tk()
        app = Application(master=root)
        app.mainloop()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

I've removed the following lines:

```
    self.master = master
    self = tk.Frame(self.master)
```

and added(for SettingsFrame):

```
    super().__init__(master)
```

Comment: This answer would be better if you explained what you did differently, otherwise we have to compare your answer to the original code line-by-line and character-by-character.